# Programatically moving around a map is jittery

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

In my mapbox/leaflet app I'm using the following code in a loop to follow a route a round a map

```
map.setView(microLineArray[microIteration], zoom);
```

microLineArray is the array of lat longs that the route follows.

It plays very odd though because of the tiles loading in.

As I am only using a couple of zoom levels and only covering the USA for the route playing is it possible to pre-load the tiles at all. If so how would I go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There is some discussion happening about this on the google group @ https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leaflet-js/nWk2k0FySRo. Sounds like some people are making phantom/hidden/offset map containers that contain more tiles than the user's map viewport.

So if you know where your routes are "generally" going to be...create another map container and use `setView` to get it moving & requesting tiles that you need prior to the user's map container.

Additionally, there is an old plugin called [Leaflet.TileBuffer](https://github.com/olizilla/Leaflet.TileBuffer) that sounds like it does exactly what you want - however compatibility with latest versions appears unknown.

You will probably also want to consider forcing `unloadInvisibleTiles` to `false`.